# How to unzip .rar with password?

Tags: r, unzip, password-encryption, unrar

I have a .rar archive that contains a file csv. The .rar has a password and I want to read it with R Studio ( the csv is the only file into the .rar).

I tried to do it with the following code:

```
library(Hmisc)

getZip("datos/diarios.rar", password = "israel")
```

But R returned this:

```
A connection with                                                                                    
description "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c unzip -p -P israel datos/diarios.rar"
class       "pipe"                                                                  
mode        "r"                                                                     
text        "text"                                                                  
opened      "closed"                                                                
can read    "yes"                                                                   
can write   "yes"
```

How can I resolve this problem?

---

When I run `read.csv` on it, it doesn´t work. Look at:

```
read.csv(gzfile("datos/diarios.zip", open = ""), header = T)
```

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
> quote, : more columns than column names In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
> quote, : line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls 2: In
> read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, :
> line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls

Comment: From the help page it seems you would for example, use `read.csv` on this

Comment: it doesn´t work. Look at: in read.csv(gzfile("datos/diarios.zip", open = ""), header = T)             Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls

Comment: that now seems like more of an issue with the data and read.csv rather than opening the compressed file. Unfortunately that is a bit hard to troubleshoot without the data. Are you able to open it in a text editor to have a look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is *test.csv* containing a data frame stored in the archive *test.rar*. We may open it using the command line mode of [*7zip*](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) using the `system()` command. This is virtually a .bat file executed from R, and we just have `paste` together the command.

```
z7 <- shQuote("C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe")  ## path to yoour 7zip.exe
arch <- "V:/test.rar"  ## path to archive
temp <- tempdir()  ## creating a temporary directory
pw <- "1234"  ## provide password
```

Now using `paste`, the command could look like this

```
(cmd <- paste(z7, "x", arch, "-aot", paste0("-o", temp), paste0("-p", pw)))
# [1] "\"C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe\" x V:/test.rar -aot -oC:\\Users\\jay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp67ZAPK -p1234"
```

(`x`: extract `-aot`: suffix existing file in order to not be overwritten, `-o`: output directory, `-p`: provide password)

which we'll execute with `system()`

```
system(cmd)
dat <- read.csv(paste0(temp, "/test.csv"))
dat
#   X X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1 1  1  4  7 10
# 2 2  2  5  8 11
# 3 3  3  6  9 12

unlink(temp, recursive=TRUE)  ## unlink the tempdir to clean up
```